# Should VirtualHost <Directory> block be contained within the <VirtualHost> stanza?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, apache-virtualhost

I often see examples of VirtualHost configurations where `<Directory>` blocks are placed outside of the `<VirtualHost>` stanza like this:

```
# /etc/httpd/conf.d/example1.conf

<Directory /var/www/html/example1>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log_example1"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log_example1" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Isn't the following example with the `<Directory>` block contained *within* the `<VirtualHost>` stanza more semantically correct?

```
# /etc/httpd/conf.d/example2.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /var/www/html/example2>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAlias example.org
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log_example2"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log_example2" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The second method seems correct to me since the  block pertains to the individual VirtualHost and if necessary will override settings in the main httpd.conf.

Edit:  The second method would require duplication of the `<Directory>` block if TLS/SSL is enabled, which isn't very DRY.  For this reason the first method seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

From the Apache doc on [Configuration Sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging):

> - [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) is processed in the order shortest directory component to longest. For example, `<Directory "/var/web/dir">` will be processed before `<Directory "/var/web/dir/subdir">`.
> - If multiple [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) sections apply to the same directory they are processed in the configuration file order.
> - Sections inside [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) sections are **applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition**. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

Both snippets are correct, as is your assumption.